# Problema al deplegar Laravel 9 en Servidor de produccion (Con Mods : Alias y Rewrite )

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-8, deployment

tengo un problema con mi proyecto laravel, y es que no consigo que se despliegue bien.

Comento la configuracion de mi servidor (`Ubuntu Server 20.04`):

He pasado de `PHP 7.*` a `PHP 8.1` , para poder usar nuevos proyectos que he estado desarrollado en `laravel 9.*` . Por tanto borré toda versión anterior de PHP a la mencionada.

Por otro lado, tengo  activado en apache el modulo de `rewrite` y `alias` para tener diferentes proyectos de laravel en un mismo servidor apache bien ordenado.

Luego en mi **configuración apache (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`):

Tengo la siguiente configuracion para mi proyecto de laravel 9:

```
Redirect "/cv_backend" "https://mi-dns/cv_backend/public"

.......
         <Directory "/var/www/html/cv_backend/public">
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
              AllowOverride All
             Require all granted
         </Directory>
 .......

 Alias /cv_backend '/var/www/html/cv_backend/public'
```

Finalmente, el `.htaccess` de mi proyecto laravel es el siguiente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase '/cv_backend'

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Bueno, pues el problema es que cuando accedo a la ruta (`https://mi-dns/cv_backend/`) me abre el sistema de archivos en vez del public :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que cuando sale esto es porque no está pillando el directorio `/public` bien por algun motivo, pero deberia de cogerlo bien con mi configuracion.

Información adicional:

Si añado `../public` sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O sea que hay algun problema con la url y los alias pero no detecto el que.

Answer (score 0):

> He pasado de PHP 7.* a PHP 8.1 , para poder usar nuevos proyectos...

No era necesario, ni recomendable borrar PHP 7.4 Pero como ya está hecho y me evito la explicación.

> Por otro lado, tengo activado en apache el módulo de rewrite y alias para tener diferentes proyectos de laravel en un mismo servidor apache bien ordenado.

Genial! entonces usemoslo.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf sirve cuando se tiene un solo dominio en el servidor.
En tu caso lo desactivaremos y crearemos hoy tusitio.com.conf Y a medida que necesites tusitio-1.com.conf tusitio-n.com.conf
Siendo tusitio.com el dominio con y sin www.

Es correcto que pongas tu proyecto en /var/www/html/cv_backend Aunque yo prefiero /var/www/html/tusitio.com para que sea más deducible todavía ;-? Teniendo en cuenta que el dominio es tusitio.com

Desactivar site por defecto

```
a2dissite 000-default
```

*Sustituir tusitio.com por el dominio correcto*

Crear

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/tusitio.com.conf
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName tusitio.com
        ServerAlias www.tusitio.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@tusitio.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tusitio.com/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/tusitio.com/public>
            AllowOverride All
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Activa el sitio web

```
a2ensite tusitio.com.conf
```

Sale

```
a2ensite tusitio.com.conf
Site tusitio.com already enabled
```

Comprueba la configuración

```
apachectl -t
```

Sale

```
apachectl -t
Syntax OK
```

En caso positivo, reinicio Apache

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

En cuanto a .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Con esta configuración te funcionara el protocolo http. Lo podras ver en http://tusitio.com y http://www.tusitio.com

El paso siguiente será habilitar el https, elegir con o sin www. Proxy's etc...
Pero cada paso es apasionante.